# Is it possible to write conditional statements in a pandoc template based on variable values?

Tags: pandoc

The `default.beamer` pandoc default template for LaTex beamer has this line:

```
$if(theme)$
\usetheme{$theme$}
$endif$
```

Does the test for a specific theme work as well? Something like:

```
$if(theme)$
   \usetheme{$theme$}
   $if(Berlin)$
     \setbeamertemplate{headline}
     {}
   $endif$
 $endif$
```

In the [Pandoc - Pandoc User Guide](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates), I've found this:

```
$if(variable)$
X
$else$
Y
$endif$
```

> This will include X in the template if variable has a non-null value;
>   otherwise it will include Y. X and Y are placeholders for any valid
>   template text, and may include interpolated variables or other
>   conditionals. The $else$ section may be omitted.

And more info on looping over variables with multiple values, however I can't seem to find information on how to test for a specific variable value - not `true` or `false`, but `Darmstadt` or `Berlin` in the specific example of a LaTex Beamer Theme.

Can this work somehow?

Comment: Any news here? Did you happen to find an answer? I've stumbled across [this](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) but haven't used it yet.

Comment: bug report about comparison in conditional: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3697

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a LaTeX conditional like

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

$if(theme)$
   \usetheme{$theme$}
   \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{$theme$}{Berlin}{%
   \setbeamertemplate{headline}}{%
   % if false
   }}%
$endif$
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc itself does not allow this out of the box.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Writing custom filter or looking for it. Pandoc filters have document serialized to JSON on both input and output. Having such a filter, you can mark sections using [custom heading attributes](http://pandoc.org/README.html#header-identifiers).
2. Preprocess Pandoc input using any preprocessor like mentioned [here](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/).

For me, second approach is preferred, because:

- not everything in Pandoc can be annotated with custom attributes;
- headings model is flat, e.g. heading is not an attribute of something like section, but only a place in the text.